# Emulating table with 'div inline-block's, "input" resists

Tags: html, css

Here is example:

http://jsbin.com/nulocufoka/1/

The cell with `input` control is for some reason "jumps out".

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="cell gray">item 1</div>
  <div class="cell gray">
    <div>
      <input type="text" value="1"> piece
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell gray">68</div>
  <br>

  <div class="cell gray">item 2</div>
  <div class="cell gray">
    <div>
      <input type="text" value="1"> piece
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell gray">18</div>
  <br>

  ...    

</form>
```

css:

```
.cell {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    height: 40px;
}

.gray {
    background: #ebebeb;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have styled the `input` with `width:80%` (so it fits) and also `.cell` with `vertical-align: top;`, this will stop the "cell" from moving up.

As an example:

[**Demo Here**](http://jsbin.com/puvepunodi/1/)

```
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  height: 40px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.gray {
  background: #ebebeb;
}

.cell1 {
  /* ??? */
}

input {
  width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I know your problem.. put the `piece` after the end of the div.

```css
.cell {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    height: 40px;
}
.gray {
    background: #ebebeb;
}
.cell1 {
    /* ??? */
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="cell gray">item 1</div>
    <div class="cell gray">
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="1"></div>piece
    </div>
    <div class="cell gray">68</div>
    <br>
    <div class="cell gray">item 2</div>
    <div class="cell gray">
        <div>
    <div class="cell1">
      <input>
    </div> piece
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell gray">18</div>
    <br>
</form>
```